# How can I stop a svg drawing over and over again when scrolling

Tags: javascript, svg

With the code below I have got all the paths to draw on scroll down and it reverses the draw on scroll up which I need. But is there a way to stop svgs from drawing repeatedly when scrolling on a bigger screen? A the moment it just seems to draw in a continuous loop when scrolling on bigger screens.

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll(".path");
// calculate path length and init
drawPaths(paths);

// Find scroll percentage on scroll 
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  drawPaths(paths);
});
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  drawPaths(paths);
});

function drawPaths(path) {
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight) * 3;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = scrollPercentage;
  paths.forEach((path) => {
    var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

    var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  border: solid thin black;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" viewBox="0 0 100 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="m 10 10 h 80" class="path" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  <path d="m 10 20 h 80 v 10 h -80" class="path" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</svg>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain from the updated code Snippet what the problem is.